# Can a walker be stopped?

Tags: c#, metaprogramming, antlr4

I have a ParseTree listener implementation that I'm using to fetch global-scope declarations in standard VBA modules:

```
public class DeclarationSectionListener : DeclarationListener
{
    private bool _insideProcedure;

    public override void EnterVariableStmt(VisualBasic6Parser.VariableStmtContext context)
    {
        var visibility = context.visibility();
        if (!_insideProcedure && visibility == null 
            || visibility.GetText() == Tokens.Public
            || visibility.GetText() == Tokens.Global)
        {
            base.EnterVariableStmt(context);
        }
    }

    public override void EnterConstStmt(VisualBasic6Parser.ConstStmtContext context)
    {
        var visibility = context.visibility();
        if (!_insideProcedure && visibility == null
            || visibility.GetText() == Tokens.Public
            || visibility.GetText() == Tokens.Global)
        {
            base.EnterConstStmt(context);
        }
    }

    public override void EnterArg(VisualBasic6Parser.ArgContext context)
    {
        return;
    }

    public override void EnterSubStmt(VisualBasic6Parser.SubStmtContext context)
    {
        _insideProcedure = true;
    }

    public override void EnterFunctionStmt(VisualBasic6Parser.FunctionStmtContext context)
    {
        _insideProcedure = true;
    }

    public override void EnterPropertyGetStmt(VisualBasic6Parser.PropertyGetStmtContext context)
    {
        _insideProcedure = true;
    }

    public override void EnterPropertyLetStmt(VisualBasic6Parser.PropertyLetStmtContext context)
    {
        _insideProcedure = true;
    }

    public override void ExitPropertySetStmt(VisualBasic6Parser.PropertySetStmtContext context)
    {
        _insideProcedure = true;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to tell the tree walker to stop walking? Say I have a VBA module like this:

```
Public Const foo = 123
Public bar As String

Public Sub DoSomething()
    ' some code
End Sub

' ...
' 10K more lines of code
' ...

Private Function GetSomething() As String
     ' some code 
End Function
```

I would like the tree walker to stop walking the parse tree as soon as it enters `Public Sub DoSomething()`, for I'm not interested in anything below that. Currently I'm walking the entire parse tree, just not doing anything with whatever I pick up within a procedure scope.

Is there a way, from within a parse tree listener implementation, to tell the walker to stop walking the tree?

Comment: Well I guess I could throw an exception and that would possibly kill the walker. But I'd like a non-violent way if possible :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do either of the following:

1. Throw an exception, such as a [CancellationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CancellationException.html)
2. Create a new class which extends `ParseTreeWalker`, and provide your own implementation of [`walk`](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/tree/ParseTreeWalker.html#walk(org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTreeListener,%20org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTree)) which understands the cancellation concept you need. It would make sense to start with the [current implementation of `walk`](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/runtime/Java/src/org/antlr/v4/runtime/tree/ParseTreeWalker.java) and modify it to meet your needs.